# How to set String key in recyclerview-selection in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am implementing `RecyclerView` and want to get details of selected items.
I am following a tutorial given [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-selection-support-to-a-recyclerview--cms-32175). But I want to get some string key instead of item position.

For example, if i do like this:

```
for (selection in selectionTracker?.selection!!)
    Log.e("tag", selection.toString())
```

I get indexes as output, but I want to get string keys here.

But I don't know what further changes should be made if I do like this:

```
fun getItemDetails() = object: ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
    override fun getSelectionKey() = itemId
    override fun getPosition() = adapterPosition
}
```

and change it into:

```
fun getItemDetails() = object: ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
    override fun getSelectionKey() = myData[adapterPosition].myKey // a string
    override fun getPosition() = adapterPosition
}
```

----EDIT----
These are my codes:

The adapter class:

```
class AdapterSubjectsIndexRV (
    private val indexList: ArrayList<ModelSubjectsIndex>,
    val itemClick: (String) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSubjectsIndexRV.MyViewHolder>() {

    // every recycler view item has unique id
    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder.
    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val courseValue = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.course_value)!!
        val courseCode = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.course_code)!!
        val courseName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.course_name)!!
        val progressValue = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.progress_value)!!
        val progressBar = itemView.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_bar)!!
        val selectedOverlay = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.subjects_card_view_selected)!!

        // set click events
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                itemClick(courseCode.text.toString())
            }
        }

        // get item details
        fun getItemDetails() = object: ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<String>() {
            // override fun getSelectionKey() = itemId
            override fun getSelectionKey() = indexList[adapterPosition].courseCode
            override fun getPosition() = adapterPosition
        }

    }

    // lookup class
    class MyItemDetailsLookup(private val rv: RecyclerView): ItemDetailsLookup<String>() {
        override fun getItemDetails(e: MotionEvent): ItemDetails<String>? {
            val v = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
            return if (v != null) {
                (rv.getChildViewHolder(v) as MyViewHolder).getItemDetails()
            } else null
        }
    }

    // set tracker
    var tracker: SelectionTracker<Long>? = null

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AdapterSubjectsIndexRV.MyViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.subjects_card, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.courseValue.text = indexList[position].courseValue
        holder.courseCode.text = indexList[position].courseCode
        holder.courseName.text = indexList[position].courseName
        holder.progressValue.text = "${indexList[position].progress}%"
        holder.progressBar.progress = indexList[position].progress

        // Highlight the item if it's selected
        holder.selectedOverlay.visibility = if (tracker!!.isSelected(position.toLong())) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
    }

    // Return the size of your data set (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = indexList.size

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }
}
```

And this is how I am setting my fragment:

```
val rvAdapter = AdapterSubjectsIndexRV(getSubjectsIndexList(subjectsList)) {
    // if not in selection mode
    if (selectionTracker?.selection?.size() == 0) {
        listener.showSubjectDetails(it)
    }
}

// set recycler view
val recyclerView = theView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.subjects_recycler_view)
recyclerView.apply {
    setHasFixedSize(true)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    adapter = rvAdapter
}

// set selection tracker
selectionTracker = SelectionTracker
     .Builder<Long>(
        "subjects_index_selection",
        recyclerView,
        StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView),
       AdapterSubjectsIndexRV.MyItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
        StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
   ).withSelectionPredicate(
        SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()
   ).build()

rvAdapter.tracker = selectionTracker

if(savedInstanceState != null)
       selectionTracker?.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

return theView
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the generic type from `<Long>` to `<String>`, then you will be able to return a string key.

```
fun getItemDetails() = object: ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<String>() {
    override fun getSelectionKey() = myData[adapterPosition].myKey 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It is showing error in the tracker builder, at argument `MyLookup(my_rv)`

Comment: Well, I don't have your code nor the error, how can I know what's wrong there? But according to `recyclerview-selection` library, the generic type <K> specifies the selection key type. I am assuming that the constructor of `MyLookup(...)` is still accepting an `.ItemDetails<Long>`, in which case you will also have to change it to <String>, here and in all there other places where this type is stored.

Comment: SelectionTracker<Long>, and  SelectionTracker.Builder<Long> also have to be changed to <String> if your selection key is string.
What does the error say?

Comment: It is showing error at `StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView)` in builder and at `tracker!!.isSelected(position.toLong())` in `onBindViewHolder` in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused by your code, but the best way to get the details is to do it on the `onBindViewHolder method. Call your on click method and then within that do your method to get the string.

Comment: I want to select multiple items and delete them at once. How to select multiple items is given in the tutorial. But for deleting them I want my own keys as I have shown.